# Regular expressions removing last letter from string

Tags: javascript, replace

When i use this function it removes the last letter from the string. It should only replace linebreaks with 
 tags. What is wrong?

```
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, breakTag);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your pattern matches any single character that's *not* `>` or carriage-return or line feed, but it doesn't add that back to the result string.  Thus it always eats the last character before the line break.

Try:

```
return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, "$1" + breakTag);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
 return str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)*$/, breakTag)
```

(I've used the `$` to match the end of the string)

Comment: There's no need to escape the '\' character when using a regular expression literal; in fact, it's explicitly wrong if what the pattern intends to match is carriage-return line-feed pairs. Also you left off the second parameter to `.replace()`.

Comment: true. it's all because of my blind fear of escaping... I've edited, thank you